# React Context api value does not get updated on other components in development mode but works in production build for gatsby project

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to upgrade my project from Gatsby 3 to Gatsby 5 along with that I'm making a react version upgrade from react 16.13.1 to react 18.2.0. I was able to successfully make the upgrade but my values from context api does not get updated in other components instead retains the initialized values. This only happens when i run the project in development mode but works fine in production build.

Here is the example of my code

```
        export const PageMetadataContext = createContext({
        slug: undefined as string | undefined,
        blogTitle: undefined as string | undefined,
        blogShortDescription: undefined as string | undefined,
        displayPageName: undefined as string | undefined,
        preferredLanguage: undefined as string | undefined,
        location: undefined as string | PageProps['location'] | undefined,
        pagePaths: {} as { [key: string]: string },
    });
    
    const PageTemplate: React.FC<Props> = ({
        data,
        pageContext,
        location,
        ...props
    }) => {
        const [pageMetadata, setPageMetadata] = useState({
            slug: elements.slug.value,
            blogTitle: blogTitle,
            blogShortDescription: blogShortDescription,
            displayPageName: displayPageName,
            preferredLanguage: preferredLanguage,
            location: location,
            pagePaths: props?.pageResources?.json?.pageContext?.paths,
        });
    
        return (
    
            <PageMetadataContext.Provider value={pageMetadata}>
                <NavigationComponent name={component.system.type} key={`${component.__typename}${idx}`} {...component?.elements} />
            </PageMetadataContext.Provider>
    
        )

 }
```

This is my navigation component code

```
const NavigationComponent = ({ name, ...props }: { name: string }) => {
    let Component = Components[name];

    const pageMetadata = React.useContext(PageMetadataContext)
    console.log(pageMetadata)
// output{slug: undefined, blogTitle: undefined, blogShortDescription: undefined, displayPageName: undefined, preferredLanguage: undefined, …}    
        if (!Component) {

        return null;
    }

    return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

when I debug and see the PageMetadata variable in provider is updated in pagetemplate component where as when i console.log in NavigationComponent the context isn't updated

here is the current project package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@babylonjs/core": "6.10.0",
        "@babylonjs/gui": "6.10.0",
        "@babylonjs/loaders": "6.10.0",
        "@kontent-ai/gatsby-components": "^10.0.0",
        "@kontent-ai/gatsby-source": "^10.0.0",
        "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
        "@rshackleton/gatsby-transformer-kontent-image": "^2.1.0",
        "@types/react-modal": "^3.12.0",
        "algoliasearch": "^4.18.0",
        "axios": "^0.25.0",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
        "framer-motion": "^6.2.6",
        "gatsby": "^5.11.0",
        "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-algolia": "^1.0.3",
        "gatsby-plugin-breakpoints": "^1.3.6",
        "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^5.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^6.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-readingtime": "^3.0.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.7.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^6.11.0",
        "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^6.11.0",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.11.0",
        "html-react-parser": "^4.0.0",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.24",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
        "proxy-polyfill": "^0.3.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
        "react-babylonjs": "3.1.17",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dropdown": "^1.9.2",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
        "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.22.0",
        "react-jotform-embed": "^1.1.3",
        "react-modal": "^3.14.3",
        "react-player": "^2.9.0",
        "react-select": "^5.2.2",
        "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
        "react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
        "sharp": "^0.30.1",
        "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack": "^5.69.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.4",
        "@loadable/babel-plugin": "^5.13.2",
        "@loadable/webpack-plugin": "^5.15.2",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/react": "^7.0.24",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.1",
        "@types/node": "^18.16.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
        "@types/react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "@types/react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.22.2",
        "@types/react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "29.5.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-preset-gatsby": "^2.7.0",
        "chalk": "^5.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.21.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
        "cypress": "^9.5.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2": "^1.1.27",
        "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
        "husky": "^4.3.6",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "inquirer": "^7.1.0",
        "jest": "^29.1.1",
        "jest-junit": "^12.2.0",
        "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
        "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "postcss-custom-properties": "^12.1.4",
        "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
        "postcss-mixins": "^9.0.1",
        "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.4.0",
        "prettier": "^2.3.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "storybook-css-modules-preset": "^1.1.1",
        "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
        "yargs-parser": "^21.0.0"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825": {
            "react": "^18.2.0"
        },
        "react-truncate": {
            "react": "^18.2.0"
        },
        "@rshackleton/gatsby-transformer-kontent-image": {
            "gatsby": "^5.11.0",
            "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.11.0"
        }
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "gatsby": "^5.11.0"
    },
     "resolutions": {
        "react-error-overlay": "6.0.11"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css}": "prettier --write"
    },
    "jest-junit": {
        "outputDirectory": "test/results/",
        "outputName": "unit.xml"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=18.0.0"
    }
```

Would like to know what is causing this behavior as this was working fine in the older version